# Why select item and click event response slowly in mainwindow,but showdialog is normal?

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

A page contains a GridControl,in main window,i select row by clicking with a pronounced delay,change very slowly,but i showdialog this page,select item smoothly.
Other controls also has response delay in mainwindow.

in mainwindow

[image]

showdialog

[image]

Comment: **1)** `ShowDialog` shows a _modal_ window.  That means control won't return to the application until it closes.  More importantly, modal windows have the benefit of a dedicated Windows Message Pump processing which generally means the rest of your app will freeze giving a potential boost to your window.  **2)** It's possible your dialog isn't performing the same amount of processing as the app **3)** DevExpress, Telerik and other 3rd party control vendors are notorious for making widgets that suck

Comment: Thanks.I use  ```window.Show``` method  and ``DataGrid```  Control  also  response slowly.